# Schema validation failed with error optimization.styles should be boolean

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular11

I updated `angular.json` with the following config to enable inlineCritical CSS

```
"optimization": { 
  "scripts": true,
  "styles": {
    "minify": true,
    "inlineCritical": true
  },
  "fonts": true
}
```

When I try to build the project I get the following error

[image: Error]

and here is my ng config

```
Angular CLI: 11.1.4
Node: 14.15.5
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 11.2.0
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, localize, material, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1100.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1100.7
@angular-devkit/core            11.0.7
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.1.4
@angular/cli                    11.1.4
@schematics/angular             11.1.4
@schematics/update              0.1101.4
rxjs                            6.6.3
typescript                      4.1.5
```

Comment: Are you sure you are on Angular 11.1?

Comment: I am using Angular 11.2

Comment: Cli also on 11.2..? If so, this should work fine..? Unless Imm missing something obvious..

Comment: Latest CLI version I see is 11.1.4. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli

Comment: Should work with v11.1.x - weird..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, based on [this answer](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20012#issuecomment-776525055) `@angular-devkit/build-angular 0.1100.7` is outdated. Updating it manually fixed the issue. Not sure why `npm update` din't update it